# Guid? in LINQ (Nullable might be Null)

Tags: linq, null

the x.Status is a Guid?, so it might be NULL.

How can I formulate this query without warnings that the nullable might be null?;)

```
  bookings = bookings
        .Where(x =>
               ((Guid)x.Status).IsEmpty()
        ).ToList();
```

EDIT: What I really want it a list of booking where Status is either NULL or Empty.

Comment: Well what do you want to do if `x.Status` *is* null?

Comment: treat it same as Empty, so that it's not included

Comment: Okay, so firstly that information should be in the question, and secondly have you tried to implement that at all? For example: `x => x.Status == null || x.Status.Value.IsEmpty()`?

Comment: (Although note that in your current logic, only entries with an empty status are *included*, whereas your comment makes it sounds like you want the reverse of that...)

Comment: Ah, yeah, x => x.Status == null || x.Status.Value.IsEmpty() is working;) Thanks